# Filtering rails model with unknown data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

I am grabbing a list of open buckets for a particular user with the following code.

```
@open_buckets = Buckets.order("buckets.id ASC").where(:user_id => @user.id)
```

There is also a concept of private buckets for the user. I only want the private buckets to be returned when the logged in user is the owner of the bucket. The private field is a boolean. Can I somehow change my query so all users get the public buckets and only the owners get their private buckets and public buckets?

The only thing I thought of was to check to see if the logged in user was the same as the user  whose buckets are being requested and do a different query. Something like below.

```
if :session["user_id"] => :user_id
    @open_buckets = Buckets.order("buckets.id ASC").where(:user_id => @user_id)
else
    @open_buckets = Buckets.order("buckets.id ASC").where(:user_id => @user_id).where(:private => true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, although I disagree with using one view (or one list/partial, more specifically) to display two different types of information, here is a way you could do what you're looking for:

```
@buckets = Buckets.order("buckets.id ASC").where(:user_id => @user_id, :private => false)
@buckets += @buckets.where(:private => true) if current_user.id == user.id
```

You could also create some cool scopes to handle this semi-complex logic in the model, where it should be, and also utilize your associations more fully:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@buckets = @user.buckets.public
@buckets += @user.buckets.private if @current_user == @user
respond_with @buckets = @buckets.order("buckets.id asc")
```

and the `Buckets` model:

```
scope :public, where(:private => false)
scope :private, where(:private => true)
```

As a side note, model class names should always be singular. You have `Buckets` in your example, so if that's not a typo then I recommend going back and changing it if it's practical to do so. It will cause confusion further down the line, especially for future developers of your application.

Comment: Regarding not using 2 views. Just 1 view but the data coming from the controller could have more rows depending on the user that is currently logged in. There are also more buttons enabled if the owner user is looking at his own bucket list. Do you think it is better to have 2 views each going to a different action? 1 for the owner and another for everyone else? Yes Buckets was a typo. It is singular. Thanks for the warning. I will check out the scope stuff as well.

Comment: I like brickers scopes - and then you can do model testing instead on controller too -always better :)

Comment: @Brian please check the `respond_with` in my above code, I updated it to add `@buckets = ` so that it will actually work.

Comment: @Brian - One view file (ie, buckets/index.html.erb) is fine. However, within that view, if it were me, I would split it up into two partials - `_private.html.erb` and `_public.html.erb`. This eliminates the need for stuff like `"Show these buttons" if bucket.private`. You can use a shared partial between the two for shared elements of each bucket. I use a lot of partials to help stay DRY, I guess that some other developers might say it's not worth the performance loss to be rendering a lot of partials per page. This is just my personal preference, you should do what makes most sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

A `named_scope` (or just `scope` [in Rails 3](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html)) can do it.

```
class Bucket
  ...

  named_scope :visible_buckets_for, lambda {|user| { :conditions=>["private = 'f' OR (private = 't' and user_id = ?)", current_user.id], :order=>"buckets.id ASC" } }
```

Where 'current_user' is whatever method you have to retrieve the `id` of the currently logged in user, and `'t'` is a DB-specific representation of a `true` value. Some DB's use "true", or any non-zero number.

Then you call it like:

```
 > Bucket.visible_buckets_for(current_user)
=> [<#Bucket1>, <#Bucket2>, <#Bucket3> ... ]
```

...which is an array of `Bucket` objects, sorted by `id`.

You can pass any user to that named scope, in case you need to find this out for more than just the current user.